# Provide Maven dependencies while launcing Spark application programatically

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to launch multiple Spark streams programmatically those depend on external jar files.

First approach I tried was to execute "SparkSubmit.main(argument)" statement from within my Java program where "argument" is a String array consisting of parameters such as --master, --class. This worked fine, but it was able to launch only a single Stream.

1st approach code snippet:

String command = buildCommand();

SparkSubmit.main(command);

Value of "command" would be something similar to 
--master [master] --class [StreamingClass] --repositories [Maven Repository] --packages [lot of Maven coordinates] [Jar File Name] [Required Command Line Parameters]

Next approach was to try ProcessBuilder to spawn multiple threads; with each thread launching a separate "SparkSubmit.main(command)" . This did not work. I could see process ids on Unix, but for some reason the data received on Kafka was not processed.

Third approach was to try SparkLauncher. However, I am a at a loss how to specify all these external jar files in form of Maven coordinates and repository using SparkLauncher. SparkLauncher.EXECUTER_EXTRA_CLASSPATH cannot be used as I don't want to specify classpath. SparkLauncher.EXECUTOR_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS may be used, but not sure what keys should be used to specify repository and packages. (--repositories and --packages or something else).

Don't want to create a uber jar as its size is over 50M.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

--Shri

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by launching ProcessBuilder with spark-submit as a command. This is similar to SparkLauncher (based on the Spark source code).

As a side note, since the requirement was to launch multiple streams each with its own JSSC, I ended up using thread as well.

End implementation was something like this

```
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("------------ Starting thread ");
                try {
                    launchWithProcessBuilder(jobService); // Job service is collection of attributes such as sparkmaster, repositories, packages etc
                } catch (SparkStreamException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

private void launchWithProcessBuilder(SparkStreamJobService jobService) {
    String sparkSubmitCommand = jobService.getSparkHome() + "/bin/spark-submit";
    List <String> command = getSparkSubmitCommandAsList(sparkSubmitCommand, jobService);

    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

thanks